# Change StandardAnalyzer Lucene

Tags: java, lucene, tokenize, standardanalyzer

I'm trying to search documents by title with StandardAnalyzer of lucene 4.10.3. I read the quotes from a file and the I add the double quotation marks for constructing the query with this:

```
Query query = parser.parse("\""+doc.get("title")+"\"");
```

The problem is that when it reads the quote PHILIPPINES SAYS DEBT PACT "BETTER THAN MEXICO'S lucene returns this error

```
Cannot parse '"PHILIPPINES SAYS DEBT PACT "BETTER THAN MEXICO'S"': Lexical error at line 1, column 52.  Encountered: <EOF> after : ""
```

How can I solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the quote in the text you are searching for needs to be escaped.  You can escape text to be searched using [`QueryParser.escape`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParserBase.html#escape(java.lang.String)):

```
Query query = parser.parse("\"" + QueryParser.escape(doc.get("title")) + "\"");
```